# Can you compile code on the fly in Silverlight?

Tags: .net, silverlight, compiler-construction

I should clarify that I am looking for a client-side solution.

Alternatively, is there a C# compiler written in managed code?

Comment: As I understand it, the DLR is your only option on the client. See: http://silverlight.net/learn/dynamiclanguages.aspx.

Comment: Without full trust, that is...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**On the Client**

Take a look at the [Dynamic Language Runtime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime) if you're using Silverlight 2.0:

- http://www.silverlightexamples.net/post/Execute-Code-String-at-Runtime-with-Silverlight-20-DLR.aspx
- http://silverlight.net/learn/dynamiclanguages.aspx

---

**Server or Client with Full Trust**

This example uses the [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx), compiles on the server, and sends the assembly down to the client:

- http://www.cnblogs.com/baggiojing/archive/2008/11/03/1325297.html

There's a VB equivalent. They allow you to compile to disk or in memory. In most cases you can't use them on the client because they require full trust.

Other examples:

- http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2007/12/20/how-to-compile-c-3-0-code-dynamically.aspx
- http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4529/using-net-to-make-your-application-scriptable/3/

Silverlight with full trust:

- http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2008/04/27/how-to-make-silverlight-be-air.aspx
- http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Silverlight-Running-standalone-full-trust-applications.aspx